# Blender import ply file but only show orange color

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to use Blender to open .ply file. But it only shows orange color. When I use Cloud Compare/MeshLab, rgb color of this point cloud model can be seen. Anyone can help me how to show the rgb color in Blender? I'm actually Blender beginner. Really appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I finally fixed this problem, simply by installing point cloud visualizer add-on. Here is the resources I find:

https://blenderartists.org/t/point-cloud-visualizer/684180/16

and

https://github.com/SBCV/Blender-Import-Point-Cloud-Addon

Answer (score 0):

I think the orange color is showing because you selected that thing. so deselect everything(press A in 2.79 and alt+A in 2.80).

Comment: hmmm. If I deselect everything, that would black color.